# Hide div background image after upload

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, forms

Maybe this it's an easy problem, but I really don't know how to solve it. 
So I have a form that submits, among other fields, a picture. The user can upload a picture.

On the upload picture field I have a div that will preview the uploaded picture. 
This div has a background image.

I want when user uploads an image, the background image to hide or disappear. In present state, if user uploads a picture that is smaller than my background image, the div will display both pics, user's picture in front of the background.

I also want to resize div size the uploaded picture, but before upload the div must contain the background picture.

Comment: * resize div to the uploaded image size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to just put an image inside the div (that previewes the uploaded picture). This way, the div will always have a default image to show(with "upload your picture here" message), and after the user uploads a picture, the div will replace the existing one with the new one.

Thank you any way!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use an img-tag? and change the src attribute to the uploaded file. If you set a max height and width, then it will resize when the pic is smaller, and when it's bigger it will use the max values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code so I can not give a perfect answer but from what you are saying maybe you could try.

```
function changeBackgroundImage(imgheight,imgwidth,newimg){
     document.getElementById('yourbackgoundid').style.background-image = newimg;
     document.getElementById('yourbackgoundid').style.height = imgheight;
     document.getElementById('yourbackgoundid').style.width = imgwidth;
 }
```

or maybe an if statement